# convert string to object with number of occurances

Tags: javascript, object

I have tried to write a function to do this:

return the number of occurances of each letter of a string in an object case insensitive
// eg. numOfOccurances('This is great') => { t: 2, h: 1, i: 2, s: 2, g: 1, r: 1, e: 1, a: 1 }

```
function numOfOccurances(string) {
  const stringLower = string.replace(/ /g, '').toLocaleLowerCase();
  const counts = {};
  let ch;
  let count;
  let i;

  for (i = 0; i < stringLower.length; i++) {
    ch = stringLower.charAt(i);
    count = counts[ch];
    counts[ch] = count ? count + 1: 1;
  }
  console.log(stringLower);
  console.log(counts);
}
```

(it currently outputs console so i can see the output).

the output i get is:

```
Object {t: 2, h: 1, i: 2, s: 2, g: 1…}
a:1
e:1
g:1
h:1
i:2
r:1
s:2
t:2
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, why is it the result a huge list, and not: { t: 2, h: 1, i: 2, s: 2, g: 1, r: 1, e: 1, a: 1 }.     It seems to stop at g (or is this the console?) and then add return characters again in no particular order...

Comment: I am sorry everyone.  My code did work, i just did not understand how Google console shows objects.  I thought my object included {t: 2, h: 1, i: 2, s: 2, g: 1…} and a:1
e:1
g:1
h:1
i:2
r:1
s:2
t:2, but it does not.  Google console, was showing me part of my object, and then the full object, but in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting should be the expected result. I get the same thing in chrome devtools.

`Object {t: 2, h: 1, i: 2, s: 2, g: 1…}` Objects with many properties get abbreviated, thus the ellipsis. You are then able to click to expand the object and view the full list of properties.

Comment: Thanks, Conan, helpful.  Just realised that when you expand it shows the whole array vertically and in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple `reduce` on the array of characters

```js
const toLowerCase = str =>
  str.toLowerCase()

const numOccurrences = str =>
  Array.from(str, toLowerCase).reduce((acc, c) =>
    Object.assign(acc, { [c]: c in acc ? acc[c] + 1 : 1 }), {})
    
console.log(numOccurrences('This is great'))
// { t: 2, h: 1, i: 2, s: 2, ' ': 2, g: 1, r: 1, e: 1, a: 1 }
```

Comment: Great, but i also need to remove ' '.  But i can do the global replace to do that.  Thanks